# Background image not displayed

Tags: modeling

[image: Rendered View]I'm a beginner in Blender 2.8. I tried adding a background image using the environment texture, but it isn't getting displayed. Can somebody please tell me what to do?

Comment: The phrase "isn't getting displayed" is a bit vague.  Do you mean it doesn't render or that it doesn't show up in the main panel of Layout mode?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you've tried? I assume you added the environment texture to the world shader. Are you in rendered preview mode (farthest circle to the right at the top of the viewport)?

Comment: Sorry for being vague earlier. I've added the image of the rendered view.
 @ChristopherBennett

Comment: Sorry for being vague earlier. I've added the image of the rendered view.
 @Edward

Comment: Use screengrabs and not photos from your phone.

Comment: uncheck Film>Transparent

Comment: [How to take a ScreenShot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html)

Comment: @susu yeah it worked. thanks!

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thanks!